`onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` not called for RecyclerView ItemDelegate when TalkBack is activated via shortcut
I’m encountering an issue with accessibility in a RecyclerView when using RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate. The onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo method is successfully called for the RecyclerView itself, but not for its ItemDelegate. This means that individual items are not getting their accessibility node info initialized.
This issue occurs only when I activate TalkBack using the accessibility shortcut after navigating to the screen. If TalkBack is already enabled before entering the screen, everything works as expected.
recyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(object : RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView) {
            override fun getItemDelegate(): ItemDelegate {
                return object : ItemDelegate(this) {
                    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                        info.contentDescription = "Item description: $host"
                    }
                }
            }
        })


